# Did the Starlink precursor Tintin satellites ever talk to each other? If so, how? Did they demonstrate an optical communications link?

Tags: spacex, communication-satellite, starlink, optical-communication

[Tintin A and B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink_(satellite_constellation)) are the first two exploratory and testing spacecraft for SpaceX's [Starlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink_(satellite_constellation)) program.

It looks like they are in very similar orbits in both space and time, and are probably that way so that the datalink between the two can be demonstrated and put through tests along with links to ground stations.

If that is so, what technology provides link between satellites? For example, if microwaves are used, what band? If the link is optical, is it visible or infrared or UV. If in-between (e.g. THz) then roughly what frequency?

The question [What technology will SpaceX's StarLink satellites most likely use for sat-to-sat linking?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31664/12102) asks about the plan for the final Starlink constellation. Here I'm just asking about Tintin A and B.

---

Screenshots for `43216` & `43217` from N2YO.com at about `2019-03-07 at 04:50 UTC`

[image: N2YO Tintin A]  [image: N2YO Tintin B]

[image: MicroSat 2a, 2b (Tintin A, B)] Source: [Gunter's Space Page](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/microsat-2.htm)