# What company has the most satellites in orbit?

Tags: spacex, record, satellite-constellation

Ars Technica's [SpaceX to offer Starlink public beta in six months, Musk says](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/04/spacex-to-offer-starlink-public-beta-in-six-months-musk-says/) says

> Meanwhile, SpaceX [launched another 60 Starlink satellites](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/04/the-falcon-9-just-became-americas-workhorse-rocket/) yesterday. The launch, as [Musk noted](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1253084960057176068), gives SpaceX "420 operational Starlink satellites."
>
> [image]

**Question:** The SpaceX CEO's not-so-mysterious affinity for the number 420 aside, I'm wondering if SpaceX has more satellites in orbit than any other company; if so, when did that begin to be true, if not, when will it be?

**note:** By "has the most" I'm asking primarily which company owns or at least operates the most, but if there is an interesting or compelling answer based on which company *built the most* it would be good to know!

Comment: 420 = 60 x 7 but weren't there a few operational duds?

Comment: oh, perhaps [Tintin are operational?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34669/12102) (currently unanswered!)

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2021, [SpaceX has launched more than 1000 of their Starlink satellites into orbit](https://spacenews.com/spacex-surpasses-1000-satellite-mark-in-latest-starlink-launch/). Of those launched, over [**950 are currently active**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink) and in orbit. This number is a sizeable percentage of the [~3000 total active satellites in orbit](https://www.geospatialworld.net/blogs/how-many-satellites-orbit-earth-and-why-space-traffic-management-is-crucial/) and more are being added on a weekly basis.

No other company really comes close to SpaceX's numbers:

- 82 active satellites: [Iridium's communication network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridium_satellite_constellation)
- 110 active satellites: [OneWeb's internet constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneWeb_satellite_constellation#List_of_launches)
- ("over") 150 active satellites: [Planet Labs' observation flock](https://www.planet.com/products/planet-imagery/)