# Do the latest Starlink satellites use inter-satellite laser communications?

Tags: spacex, starlink, laser, optical-communication

Do the latest (as of Jan 30, 2020) Starlink satellites use [inter-satellite laser communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_communication_in_space)?

I can't find any info about that!

Comment: You think of a laser data link between two satellites in orbit or within the same satellite?

Comment: related but different because I've asked there about the final configuration, not just about "the latest satellites": [What technology will SpaceX's StarLink satellites most likely use for sat-to-sat linking?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31664/12102)

Comment: I don't see any reason to close this question; either they do or they don't, there's nothing to clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All I could find was [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starlink) which led to a variety of articles which explain the technology in depth. Not that Wikipedia is always reliable, however it stated that:

> The satellites will employ optical inter-satellite links and phased
>   array beam-forming and digital processing technologies in the Ku and
>   Ka bands, according to documents filed with the U.S. Federal
>   Communications Commission (FCC).[86][87] While specifics of the phased
>   array technologies have been disclosed as part of the frequency
>   application, SpaceX enforced confidentiality regarding details of the
>   optical inter-satellite links.[88] Early satellites are launched
>   without laser links, in October 2019 SpaceX expected satellites with
>   these links to be ready by the end of 2020.

In the additional links from the FCC technical document:

> The
>   system will also employ optical inter-satellite links for seamless network management and
>   continuity of service, which will also aid in complying with emissions constraints designed to
>   facilitate spectrum sharing with other systems.

So, to make a long answer short, there are no inter-communication abilities on the satellites which were already launched. It seems that the earlier satellites will **not have this capability**. The laser-links seem to be planned for this year.

86: [Space Exploration Holdings, LLC (15 November 2016). "SPACEX NON-GEOSTATIONARY SATELLITE SYSTEM – ATTACHMENT A". FCC Space Station Applications. Retrieved 15 February 2018.](http://licensing.fcc.gov/myibfs/download.do?attachment_key=1158350)

87: [Space Exploration Holdings, LLC (15 November 2016). "SAT-LOA-20161115-00118". FCC Space Station Applications. Retrieved 15 February 2018.](http://licensing.fcc.gov/cgi-bin/ws.exe/prod/ib/forms/reports/swr031b.hts?q_set=V_SITE_ANTENNA_FREQ.file_numberC/File+Number/%3D/SATLOA2016111500118&prepare=&column=V_SITE_ANTENNA_FREQ.file_numberC/File+Number)

88: [Wiltshire, William M. (20 April 2017). "Re: Space Exploration Holdings, LLC, IBFS File No. SAT-LOA-20161115-00118". FCC Space Station Application. Retrieved 15 February 2018.](http://licensing.fcc.gov/myibfs/download.do?attachment_key=1210294)

Documents are from the FCC licencing and are publicly available. After downloading the PDF files searching for "inter-satellite" gets to some relevant parts. Though these documents seem to lack time-line information on when this technology will be launching.