# How big does a LEO relay satellite optical communication package need to be to support cislunar operations?

Tags: communication, starlink, optical-communication, cislunar

One of the things to come out of Artemis 1 was that [NASA’s Deep Space Network was very overworked](https://spacenews.com/nasa-deep-space-network-reaches-critical-point-as-demand-grows/) supporting Orion and eight cubesats + normal operations and maintenance. This led to some slightly heated [discussions of solutions](https://twitter.com/rookisaacman/status/1697053459906728371). Now there's a reasonable amount out there about [ground based optical solutions](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/opag/july2014/posters/9-DSOC_OPAG_Poster.pdf), but I wasn't able to find good resources on size of relay satellite optical payloads.

Now SpaceX [are investigating using Starlink as relay satellites](https://www.nasa.gov/saa/domestic/36564_CSP_FSAA_NNC2236564_SpaceX_fully_executed.pdf) already, but it's unclear whether this is restricted to other objects in LEO or LEO adjacent orbits. ([Polaris Dawn](https://polarisprogram.com/dawn/) will demonstrate this service). There is a fairly drastic distance change from LEO relay to Cislunar relay, so presumably the complexity increases by a bit as well. So what I want to know is the size of the optical packages required for this to understand whether they could fit on a Starlink scale platform.

Comment: Where can we read further about the "slightly heated discussions"? [I'm not seeing much heat at that link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lAvt.jpg). Slightly related: [Will future deep space optical communications "ground stations" actually be in space, or on the ground?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48550/12102) (and links therein) and [What technology will SpaceX's StarLink satellites most likely use for sat-to-sat linking?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31664/12102)

Comment: Yeah uhoh you can't view the rest of the messages without a twitter account, but names are thrown around. It's definitely not worth subjecting yourself to getting an account to see.

Comment: Oh that's right, the bird's been recently X'ed. :-)